# Parse-platform use join in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, back4app

I am building an app using [back4app](https://back4app.com) which is base on parse-platform database.

my database schema is like this:

```
Users table:
id
User_name
....
Items table:
id (f)
Item_name
Count
.....
User item table:
Id
User_id
Item_id
item_status
item_notes
......
```

what I want to achieve is to get the `item_name` by having the `user_id` how this can be possible using `parse` in android?

**Edit**: to be clear ... every item will be defined in the `User_Item` table even if it's the same item because the user may change at any time.
that's why I want the `user_id` to get the item_name from the `items` table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to query the 'User item table' so...

First of all your `itemId` field should be a pointer to the object in the 'Items table', this way you can use `query.include("itemId");` which means that the object from the 'Items table' will also be returned with the query.

Below is an example of a full query for this:

```cs
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserItem");

query.include("itemId");

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    ParseObject item = object.getParseObject("itemId");
    String itemName = item.getString("Item_name");
  }
});
```

I don't use the android SDK so this code may not be perfect - please see the [android guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide) for more details (I lifted all this code from there).

**Edit:**

Add `query.whereEqualTo("User_id", "xxxxx");` to get the User item for the current user (replace `xxxxx` with the users Id).

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserItem");

query.include("itemId");
query.whereEqualTo("User_id", "xxxxx");

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    ParseObject item = object.getParseObject("itemId");
    String itemName = item.getString("Item_name");
  }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192602/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-fox-parse-platform-use-join-in-android). Please make sure that the answer has been [edit]ed to reflect any insights gained in the discussion.